# How to change highcharts radius according to data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have data comprised of both positive and negative values which are to be displayed in a chart. i
am trying to display data in such a way that data point of positive values is greater than that of negative values.
the following is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="demochart"></div>
        <button id="update"> Update</button>
        <script>
            Highcharts.chart('demochart', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'scatter'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    data: [15, 50, -56.5, -46.5, -22.1, -2.5, -27.7, -55.7, 76.5]
                }]
            },function(chart){
                $('#update').click(function(){
                    var data = chart.series[0].data;
                    var new_array = [];
                    new_array = data;
                    console.log(new_array);
                    for(var i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++){
                        console.log("For: "+ new_array[i].y);
                        if(new_array[i].y > 0){
                                new_array[i].y = "{y:"+ new_array[i] +",marker: {radius: 10}}"
                                console.log("If: "+ new_array[i].y);
                        }else{
                            new_array[i].y = "{y:"+ new_array[i] +",marker: {radius: 4}}"
                            console.log("Else: "+ new_array[i].y);
                        }
                    }
                    chart.series[0].setData(new_array);
                })
            });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click the update button, the size of data point value radius has to be changed.
Can this scenario will work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `update` method for points that meet your condition and change marker options. For performance reasons, it is better to set `redraw` parameter to `false` and redraw the chart after loop to avoid redrawing on every iteration.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
}, function(chart) {
    $('#update').click(function() {
        var points = chart.series[0].points;

        points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (point.y > 0) {
                point.update({
                    marker: {
                        radius: 10
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        });

        chart.redraw();
    })
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jznums3L/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw